# How create nested JSON by Kotlinx Serialization on Kotlin native

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

I creating a Shared lib by Kotlin multiplatform and I use `Kotlin Serialization` library for Serialize and Deserialize, I Implementing `Graph QL` on my project and I use below struct

```
{
 "operationName":"Operation",
 "query":"query Operation($id: ID){rres: Cards(id: $id){id}}",
 "variables":{"id": 1}
}
```

for communication with `API`, now I have a issue that I should fill a `Json` as a `Object` in `variables` by `Kotlinx.Serialization` but I don't find a way for it while I fill `varibales` as String and `API` get exception to me.

How I create a nested Json by Kotlinx.Serialization?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a class for nested Json objects and annotate it with @Serializable

```
@Serializable
class Data(
    val operationName: String,
    val query: String,
    val variables: Variables
) {
    @Serializable
    class Variables(val id: Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at here. I think this thread exactly tackles the issue of storing the object as a Json string, that is nested in another Json.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/345#issuecomment-457545923